# Setting value of 'date-time local' input box using JQuery, normal datetime selection form drop down is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetime

This is my code to display a DateTime selector with the dropdown in HTML,

```
<input id="FromDate" name="FromDate" style="width:90%" type="datetime-local"  >
```

I use the following JQuery code to set the date to the previous month,

```
var dt = new Date();
var Fromdatetime = dt.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (dt.getMonth())).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2) + "T" + ("0" + dt.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2) ; 
$("#FromDate").val(Fromdatetime)
```

After I execute the script, DateTime is set up correctly to a value one month before.
But after that, I'm unable to modify the date-time using the HTML element as like before.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month are calculated from `0` to `11` so if you want to get current month you need to add `+1` to you getMonth() function in JS - thats how it works.

Also, the reason you date is not updated is that you need to set `attr` instead of val() to your input.

Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/23h4L0fu/

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
var dt = new Date();

//Adding +1 to months
var Fromdatetime = dt.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (dt.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + dt.getDate()).slice(-2) + "T" + ("0" + dt.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + dt.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

//Using attr 
$('#FromDate').attr('value', Fromdatetime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="FromDate" name="FromDate" style="width:90%" type="datetime-local">
```