# Getting minutes from a datetime-local input add minutes, then insert into end date

Tags: javascript

My UI is pretty simple.

[image]

I have to set a start time first, and thne select a service. When changing the service, I make a backend call to get how long the service takes. From the backend end I would get back a string value like this: "10" which means 10 minutes. "60" = 60 minutes. "90" = 1 hour 30 miiuntes etc.

My code is simple.

```
            var startDateAppt = $("#apptStartTime").val().toISOString();
            var date = new Date(startDateAppt);
            console.log(date.toISOString());
            var endDate = new Date(date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+10));
            $("#apptEndTime").val(endDate.toISOString());
```

However, I am getting an error..

> The specified value "2024-02-05T22:12:00.000Z" does not conform to the
> required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by
> optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

I can not figure out why this is happening to it...

Comment: Use the `Date` methods: `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+10)` adds 10 minutes to `date`

Comment: @Barmar I then run into this error:The specified value "1707170940000" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".

Comment: You're trying to use a numeric timestamp as a date string somewhere. That doesn't seem related to my comment.

Comment: pls see updated question with new code/error @Barmar

Comment: Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#calculating_elapsed_time and milliseconds to datetime and setting a new date, particularly passing epoch timestamp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#several_ways_to_create_a_date_object

Comment: `new Date(1707170940000);` =  Mon Feb 05 2024 17:09:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) if I do console.log of it in my local time zone e.g. `const date1 = new Date(1707170940000);
console.log(date1);`

Comment: If `.val()` is returning a `Date`, perhaps give it a `Date` as well? I.e., `$("#apptEndTime").val(endDate);`? This is not tagged jQuery or the control you are using, so that the best we can do...

Comment: You may want to look at this question and its answer too: [Setting value of 'date-time local' input box using JQuery, normal datetime selection form drop down is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62751241/215552)

Answer (score 1):

`date.setMinutes()` doesn't return a date string, it modifies the date in place.

```js
$("#update").click(function() {
  var startDateAppt = $("#apptStartTime").val();
  var date = new Date(startDateAppt);
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 10 - date.getTimezoneOffset());
  $("#apptEndTime").val(date.toISOString().slice(0,16));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Start <input id="apptStartTime" type="datetime-local"><br>
End <input id="apptEndTime" type="datetime-local"><br>
<button type="button" id="update">Click</button>
```

See [Setting value of datetime-local from Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166338/setting-value-of-datetime-local-from-date) for why it's necessary to subtract the timezone offset and slice the ISO string.

Comment: ahh, i was able to figure it out but he time was wrong. the getTimezoneOffset() fixed my final issue. thank you!!